# Ember.js: How to set default options of multiple Ember.Select(s) in a single controller?

Tags: ember.js, controller, models, ember.select

This is my first Ember.js application. All Ember's examples and tutorials I found are a single controller with a single model or a single model having children models.
However, this application puts two models (companies and users) into a single controller (login) side by side. However it doesn't work very well.

[image]

Its jsbin.com code is at: [jsbin.com/cirah](http://jsbin.com/cirah/3/edit?html,js,output)

My design is: the login controller doesn't have a defined model, but two arrays of companies and users. Each of both has an _selid to indicate the current selection.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({});
App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: 'App.ApplicationAdapter',
});
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://emberjs.azurewebsites.net',
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
    }
});
App.Company = DS.Model.extend({
    company: DS.attr('string')
});
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    userName: DS.attr('string'),
    passwordHash: DS.attr('string'),
});
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource("login", { path: '/login' });
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect: function () {
        this.transitionTo('login');
    },
});
App.LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        var store = this.get('store');
        controller.set('companies', store.find('company'));
        controller.set('company_selid', 2);
        controller.set('users', store.find('user'));
        controller.set('user_selid', 3);
    },
});
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    companies: null,
    company_selid: '2',
    users: null,
    user_selid: '3',
    passwordHash: '',
    actions: {
        login: function () {
            alert('login clicked');
        },
    },
});
```

The login template contains two Ember.Select(s) for the arrays.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label for="company" class="input-group-addon ">Company:</label>
    {{view Ember.Select 
        class="form-control" 
        content=companies 
        optionValuePath="content.id"  
        optionLabelPath="content.company" 
        value="company_selid" 
        selectionBinding="company_selid"}}
</div>

<div class="input-group">
    <label for="userName" class="input-group-addon">User Name:</label>
    {{view Ember.Select
        class="form-control"
        content=users
        optionValuePath="content.id"
        optionLabelPath="content.userName"
        value=user_selid
        selection=user_selid
    }}
</div>
```

The server side returns:

```
http://emberjs.azurewebsites.net/companies?format=json
{"companies":[
    {"id":1,"company":"ABC Company"},
    {"id":2,"company":"XYZ Company"}
]}
http://emberjs.azurewebsites.net/users?format=json   
{"users":[
    {"id":101,"userName":"Aaron","passwordHash":""},
    {"id":102,"userName":"Brian","passwordHash":""},
    {"id":103,"userName":"Corey","passwordHash":""},
    {"id":104,"userName":"David","passwordHash":""}
]}
```

My questions are:

Q1: What's the Ember's best practice to use single controller to embed multiple models? I'd like to have eager loading of two arrys, should I use Ember.RSVP in login model? Or should I use ContainerView?

Q2: In my code, the default options of two Ember.Select(s) doesn't work, it's always the 1st option, even I set them twice in login controller and setupController. How to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track.

For loading the data I would load all the data in the `model` hook using [`Ember.RSVP.hash`](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js#hash-of-promises) to return an object with all the data you need loaded, and then you can set the correct elements in the controller in `setupController`.

As for the `Ember.Select`s the reason why it was not selecting the correct item was because you were not setting the value correctly.

There is 2 ways to get the currently selected item from an `Ember.Select`

1. using the [`value`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html#property_value) attribute
2. using the [`selection`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html#property_selection) attribute

The `value` attribute gets or sets the selection **by it's value**.
The `selection` attribute gets or sets the the selected element of content.
Since they represent 2 different things they should never be bound to the same property on your controller.

In your case the `value` would be the selected `model.id` and the `selection` would be the entire `model`.

Being that you wanted to set the selection using the `id` you would need to bind `company_selid` and `user_selid` to the `value` property of the `Ember.Select`.
One thing to look out for when using ember data is that ember data will create the models with the `id` as a string, so when setting the `company_selid` you need to set it as string.

I setup a working bin here: http://jsbin.com/gaduve/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, @tikotzky. It perfectly resolves my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks okay to me, just edit your .hbs like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
<label for="company" class="input-group-addon ">Company:</label>
{{#if companies}}
    {{view Ember.Select 
        class="form-control" 
        content=companies 
        optionValuePath="content.id"  
        optionLabelPath="content.company" 
        value=company_selid
        selectionBinding=company_selid}}
{{/if}}
</div>

<div class="input-group">
<label for="userName" class="input-group-addon">User Name:</label>
{{#if users}}
    {{view Ember.Select
        class="form-control"
        content=users
        optionValuePath="content.id"
        optionLabelPath="content.userName"
        value=user_selid
        selection=user_selid
    }}
{{/if}}
</div>
```

Points:

- Wrap the view with if blocks so that it will only load once the content is loaded
- Do not put quotes in content and value inside view Ember.Select

Comment: I added a new jsbin version: [jsbin.com/cirah/2/](http://jsbin.com/cirah/2/edit?html,js,output).

However, the default options are now blank, not set to 2 for company or 103 for user. Any idea on it?